# How to pass data from C# to dll

Tags: c#, dll, vb6

I have project in vb named FamServer. In it , a class named FamApp is available . In that class , a function named FamEnroll is available .
I have converted this project to dll .I have added this dll to my project . The famenroll funcion in dll is defined as below :

```
Public Function FamEnroll(strName As String, strEnrollTemplate As String, strIP As String) As String
```

I have called this dll by the following code :

```
FamServer.FamApp famApp = new FamServer.FamApp();

          famApp.FamEnroll(name, Request.Form["LearnModel"], Request.ServerVariables["REMOTE_ADDR"]);
```

But when I am running this code , I am getting the following error :

```
Exception Details: System.InvalidCastException: Unable to cast COM object of type 'FamServer.FamAppClass' to interface type 'FamServer._FamApp'. This operation failed because the QueryInterface call on the COM component for the interface with IID '{B2CC832C-CF23-4023-9C87-711F425EC323}' failed due to the following error: No such interface supported (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80004002 (E_NOINTERFACE)).
```

The stack trace is as below :

```
[InvalidCastException: Unable to cast COM object of type 'FamServer.FamAppClass' to interface type 'FamServer._FamApp'. This operation failed because the QueryInterface call on the COM component for the interface with IID '{B2CC832C-CF23-4023-9C87-711F425EC323}' failed due to the following error: No such interface supported (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80004002 (E_NOINTERFACE)).]
   System.StubHelpers.StubHelpers.GetCOMIPFromRCW(Object objSrc, IntPtr pCPCMD, IntPtr& ppTarget, Boolean& pfNeedsRelease) +0
   FamServer.FamAppClass.FamEnroll(String& strName, String& strEnrollTemplate, String& strIP) +0
   famenroll2.Page_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e) in f:\ASP.NET Projects\ASPNET\famenroll2.aspx.cs:27
   System.Web.Util.CalliEventHandlerDelegateProxy.Callback(Object sender, EventArgs e) +51
   System.Web.UI.Control.OnLoad(EventArgs e) +95
   System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() +59
   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +678
```

Why am I getting this error ? How can I solve this error ? Please help me .

Comment: your DLL uses old com technology that is incompatible with .net, you need to use a com to .net translation wrapper see https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms404285(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: I am able to use a com to .net translation wrapper . Thanks for your comment .

Comment: make sure you are using the wrapper classes and not the dll's

Comment: You tagged the question vba, which is not the same as vb.

Comment: In Solution Explorer, note that the COM component is added to the References folder in your project. How can I do that ?

Comment: You can certainly use VB6 COM components in .NET. Generally speaking, the process to do this is automatic. When you add the COM library as a project reference the interop layers (wrappers) are generated automatically and are essentially invisible. I don't understand comments to the contrary. We do this all the time.